# What is the frequency of double-hets between parent and child?

Tags: genetics

Say both parent and child are genotyped for all SNPs. In this setup we are only looking at variant positions between one parent and child - so neither parent nor child are homozygous reference (no AA/AA) in the millions of positions we are studying.

Assume all variants are biallelic and there is no *de novo* mutation (no AA/BB or BB/AA)

```
P    C
AA   AB
AB   AA
AB   AB
AB   BB
BB   AB
BB   BB
```

What is the fraction of AB/AB among these possibilites?

We are looking at all positions in the genome so the minor allele frequency (MAF) of B allele varies. You can choose whatever B frequency you like.

Comment: I'm a little confused: are the genotypes in the rows representing different loci or just different potential, non AA/AA scenarios of one locus?

Comment: Potentials. I am going to go with 1/6, regardless of B's MAF.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You say `so neither parent nor child are homozygous` while in your example you have examples where one of the two or even the two are homozygous. Then it is unclear what you mean by `no AA/BB or BB/AA`. I suppose the `/` notation separate one parent genotype from the child genotype. I don't know if you're assuming sexual reproduction and talk only about one parent or not. I think you want to assume that all `A` alleles are at the same frequency. In the same time you seem to say the MAF varies, however you say the "MAF of  `B`" varies which makes little sense.

Comment: For the above reasons, I am voting to close as unclear (four years after the question has been posted :) )

Comment: by no `AA/BB or BB/AA` I mean if the one parent we know about is AA we never BB in the child.

Comment: "I don't know if you're assuming sexual reproduction and talk only about one parent or not."
because often we only have access to one parent